# IOrderedEnumerable<T> vs. SortedSet<T>: что быстрее сериализуется?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, asp.net-web-api, сериализация, бинарное-дерево

Сделал замер, чтобы выяснить создание и итерация какой коллекции быстрее `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` или `SortedSet<T>`

```
internal class User
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DocumNumber { get; set; }
}

internal class UserDto : IComparable<UserDto>
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int DocumNumber { get; set; }
    public int CompareTo(UserDto other)
    {
        return string.Compare(this.FullName, other.FullName, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int count = 1000000;
        var users = new List<User>();
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            users.Add(new User
            {
                Name = "Name",
                Surname = "Surname",
                DocumNumber = i
            });
        }

        // IOrderedEnumerable<T>
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var userDtoList = new List<UserDto>();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            userDtoList.Add(new UserDto
            {
                FullName = $"{user.Surname} {user.Name}",
                DocumNumber = user.DocumNumber
            });
        }
        var orderedEnumerableUserDto = userDtoList.OrderBy(u => u.FullName);
        foreach (var userDto in orderedEnumerableUserDto)
        {
            // просто делаем некую работу
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("IOrderedEnumerable<T>: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        // SortedSet<T>                                                                 
        watch.Restart();
        var sortedSetUserDto = new SortedSet<UserDto>();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            sortedSetUserDto.Add(new UserDto
            {
                FullName = $"{user.Surname} {user.Name}",
                DocumNumber = user.DocumNumber
            });
        }
        foreach (var userDto in sortedSetUserDto)
        {
            // просто делаем некую работу
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("SortedSet<T>: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

По итогу трех замеров средние были таковы:

```
IOrderedEnumerable<T>: 4661 ms 
SortedSet<T>:          611 ms
```

почти в 8 раз `SortedSet<T>` оказался быстрее.

---

### Немного о IOrderedEnumerable

В начале поста я назвал `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` коллекцией. Знаю был не прав, sorry, просто не знаю, как грамотно оперировать, когда сравниваются коллекция и интерфейс.

Я не понял, как работает этот интерфейс, что за перечислитель он возвращает. Потому что если мы у обоих замеров уберем блок

```
foreach (var userDto in orderedEnumerableUserDto)
{
    // просто делаем некую работу
}
```

то увидим, что замеры показывают одинаковые результаты. Уверен, что выражение

```
var orderedEnumerableUserDto = userDtoList.OrderBy(u => u.FullName);
```

никакой сортировки не делает в памяти, иначе это заняло бы уйму времени. Там скорее всего происходит просто маркировка объектов — кто в какой очереди будет вызывается интерфейсом перечислителем `IOrderedEnumerable`, типа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Вопрос

Свои мысли по поводу `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` привел из-за того, что хотел сказать, что если бы понимал, как он работает изнутри, то возможно вопрос не возник. Ну а вопрос в следующем: **что из этих двух вариантов лучше возвращает контроллеру, который будет сериализовывать все это добро в JSON, что быстрее будет происходить?**

У меня не хватило смекалки как сделать замер скорости сериализации этих двух объектов и был бы благодарен если в качестве ответа был показан такой замер.

Comment: Сериализация использует рефлексию, поэтому, я думаю, структура данных имеет уже второстепенное значение по скорости

Comment: результат `OrderBy` сортируется в момент вызова `foreach`, в то время как для SortderSet осуществляется просто вывод, но большие затраты на вставку элементов

Comment: @Grundy т.е. сортировка происходит только когда `foreach` начинает работать? А эта сортировка предполагает создание новой отсортированный коллекции в памяти?

Comment: Конечно предполагает, Linq не изменяет последовательности, а только создаёт новые

Comment: @АндрейNOP , для сериализации в JSON, на сколько мне известно, `ASP.NET Web API` использует `DataContractJsonSerializer`. И когда на сериализацию ему будет передан `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`, то потребуется сначала время на создание отсортированной коллекции в памяти и только затем можно будет приступить к сериализации. Верно я описал конвейер?)

Comment: Да, думаю это так

Comment: @adamshakhabov не совсем понятно, какое отношение код в вопросе имеет к сериализации. Если хотите узнать, что быстрее сериализуется - возьмите конкретный сериализатор (они бывают разные, и работают совершенно по-разному. даже разные версии json.net могут работать по-разному), напишите пример сериализации на ожидаемых объемах, прогоните его через benchmarkdotnet и померяйте. а все остальное - ничем необоснованные предположения :)

Comment: Не ругайте меня @PashaPash :). К примеру, Вы упомянули `benchmarkdotnet`, а я не знал про природу его существования.  @Grundy напомнил мне об отложенной загрузке, а я это просто напросто забыл (сам взбешен). И я не знал, что результатом `Linq` (спасибо @АндрейNOP) есть создание новой коллекции. Зная, теперь об этих вещах, и замеров делать не надо, ведь в первом случае просто на создание того что будет сериализоваться уходит больше времени.

Comment: @adamshakhabov я не ругаю, я советую :)

Comment: Некорректно сравнивать конкретный класс и интерфейс, так как за интерфейсом может быть все, что угодно.

Comment: @tym32167, я в посте писал, что осознаю некорректность такого сравнения _"В начале поста я назвал IOrderedEnumerable<T> коллекцией. Знаю был не прав, sorry, просто не знаю, как грамотно оперировать, когда сравниваются коллекция и интерфейс"_

Comment: `не знаю, как грамотно оперировать, когда сравниваются коллекция и интерфейс` - я и говорю, что никак, так как коллекцию с интерфейсом не сравнивают

Comment: Все сдаюсь) Твоя взяла @tym32167

Comment: Ура, победа! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая ваша ошибка - вы используете список из миллиона одинаковых элементов. А SortedSet не хранит одинаковые элементы, то есть реально у вас внутри SortedSet хранится всего один элемент.

Если сделать все элементы разными (`Name = "Name" + i`) - то время работы SortedSet увеличится в 10 раз.

Вторая ваша ошибка - вы в разных методах используете разные алгоритмы сравнения строк!

SortedSet у вас использует наиболее быстрый алгоритм `StringComparison.Ordinal`, который сравнивает номера символов - в то время как ваш GroupBy использует медленный алгоритм `StringComparison.CurrentCulture` (который, к примеру, учитывает равенство буквы "е" и обоих форм буквы "ё" при сортировке).

Простое указание для OrderBy использовать быстрое сравнение строк (`.OrderBy(u => u.FullName, StringComparer.Ordinal);`) заметно ускоряет сортировку.

В результате у меня получилась примерно вот такая картина:

> SortedSet: 1214ms
>
> IOrderedEnumerable: 920ms

Иными словами, использование OrderBy оказалось быстрее, как и должно быть: сбалансированное бинарное дерево - довольно тяжелая структура данных, и простая сортировка массива при прочих равных всегда будет быстрее дерева (если, конечно же, для вашей задачи достаточно однократной сортировки).

---

Для подготовки данных перед сериализацией используйте OrderBy. SortedSet использовать не нужно потому что он решает совсем другую задачу.

Если нужно ускорение любой ценой - можете использовать `List<T>.Sort`, он будет малость по-быстрее.